# undefined is not an object when import external js file in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image: what's this error]
i am import external js file and call funcation in component but getting error "get  i use this code but showing undefined is not an object (evaluating _ApiHelper.ApiHelper.getPost)"

**Main login file code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Alert,
  KeyboardAvoidingView
} from "react-native";
//
import { Search } from '../Search/Search';
import { ApiHelper } from '../../api/ApiHelper'; 

export default class Login extends Component {
  static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'LoginActivity',
   };

constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    //
    //Obj = new ApiHelper();
    //

    this.state = {
      userName: '',
      password: '',
      serverName:''
    }

  }

UserRegistrationFunction = () =>{


 const { userName }  = this.state ;
 const { password }  = this.state ;
 const { serverName }  = this.state ;
  this.data =  {
      name: userName,
      email: password,
      password: serverName

    }

   alert(ApiHelper.getPost());
 //Alert.alert(returndata);

  }
```

**Import file code**

```
  const ApiHelper = {
  getPost:() => {
    return 1;

  }
}

export default ApiHelper;
```

what wrong in my code i also clear react native cache and other stuff.
thank in advance.

Comment: Either you're importing the wrong file, or you're not showing the relevant part of the code. Or maybe you didn't copy/paste the error and made a typo.

Comment: i am import right file

Comment: The error shows a call to `getdata`, which is not shown here in your code.

Comment: Turns out you made a typo. :) Now look at @mersocarlin's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ApiHelper` file exports `default`.

So in order to use it somewhere else, just import it as:

`import ApiHelper from '../../api/ApiHelper'`

Comment: @jhon Did you remove the curly brackets as well?

Comment: yes  i remove used like import ApiHelper from '../../api/ApiHelper';

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(ApiHelper)`? (without calling `getPost`)

Comment: get [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

I guess `getData` is not defined/misspelled in the ApiHelper class and the function working on the output expects an object. Since `typeof(undefined)` is not object that's why it is throwing an error.

Comment: sorry for getData it getPost i am using and it not working i didn't understand what wrong in my code